# How does server decided that the user asked a protected resource?

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security

The following quote is from [Spring security](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/technical-overview.html#common-authentication) documentation:

> Consider a typical web application's authentication process:
>
> You visit the home page, and click on a link.
>
> A request goes to the server, and the server decides that you've asked for a protected resource.
>
> [...]

It's not clear to me how the server decides that the user asked for a protected resource? Is there a special filter for that o something similar? If so, couldn't you point me out to the class?

Answer (score 1):

Its in same lines though. Hope this helps;

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-example/

Advantage is that you can configure between resources (url) as  authenticated, authorized (Assigned by roles), non-authenticated for access.

All configs happen with url patterns and roles assigned to those pattern in xml file.

Answer (score 1):

within your Spring configurations, you define what is a protected resource. For example:

```
<sec:http authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
```

means that all app-URLs that starts with "/secure/..." is a protected resource and user must be logged in before he can reach it.

Answer (score -1):

Basically there is a Filter that intercept all the requests. 
The class of that filter is `org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy`
When a request is coming from an address to be secured it verify that the user is already logged otherwyse it responds with a error status 403 or redirecting to a login page.

This configuration of secured resources is done in a configuration file.

Comment: It seems you don't understand what I wanted... I was looking for an actual Java-class, but not how it defines in xml-file.

Comment: As I said before there is a filter. That you need to configure in your web.xml. The class of that filter is org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy

Comment: DelegatingFilterProxy sounds too broad. I was looking for a specific filter in the filter chain.